# Create products (parent configurable, simple children)

Tags: php, magento

I'm attempting to create products programmatically and I can successfully create configurable and simple products, I'm just not sure how to link the two.

Here is what I'm using:

```
foreach ($products as $sku => $row)
{
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $product->setAttributeSetId(4)
        ->setTypeId('configurable')
        ->setStockData(array(
            'manage_stock'  => 0,
            'min_sale_qty'  => 0,
            'max_sale_qty'  => 0,
        ))
        ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
        ->setTaxClassId(1)
        ->setCreatedAt(time())
        ->setName($row['name'])
        ->setSku($sku)
        ->setPrice($row['price'])
        ->setCategoryIds(array(2))
        ->setStatus(1) // enabled
        ->setWeight(1)
        ->setWebsiteIDs(array(1))
        ->setDescription($row['description'])
        ->setShortDescription($row['short_desc']);

    try
    {
        $product->save();

        $parent_id = $product->getId();
        echo 'Configurable Product created: ' . $parent_id . "\n";

        if (!empty($parent_id))
        {
            foreach ($row['children'] as $child_sku => $child)
            {
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                $product->setAttributeSetId(4)
                    ->setTypeId('simple')
                    ->setStockData(array(
                        'manage_stock'  => 0,
                        'min_sale_qty'  => 0,
                        'max_sale_qty'  => 0,
                    ))
                    ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
                    ->setTaxClassId(1)
                    ->setCreatedAt(time())
                    ->setName($row['name'] . ' ' . $color)
                    ->setSku($sku . $child_sku)
                    ->setPrice($row['price'])
                    ->setcategoryIds(array(2))
                    ->setStatus(1)
                    ->setWeight(1)
                    ->setWebsiteIDs(array(1))
                    ->setDescription($row['description'])
                    ->setShortDescription($row['short_desc'])
                    ->setParentId($parent_id);

                $product->save();

                echo 'Simple product created: ' . $product->getId() . "\n";
            }

            echo "\n";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo 'Unable to create product', "\n";
        echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    }
}
```

I'm using setParentId in the child create product, but that doesn't seem to be working. It's not throwing an error, just doesn't seem to be doing anything and the products don't appear to be linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Francis ,it not proper way to add `a simple product` with `configurable product`.

`setParentId()`  is not proper way to add simple to configurable product.

Remove `setParentId()` function from  code.
You use below code

```
Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')
    ->saveProducts( $parent_id, $simpleProductIds);
```

Note If not working :you can try  $parent = $product;

Code is

```
foreach ($products as $sku => $row)
{
    $Parentproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $Parentproduct>setAttributeSetId(4)
        ->setTypeId('configurable')
        ->setStockData(array(
            'manage_stock'  => 0,
            'min_sale_qty'  => 0,
            'max_sale_qty'  => 0,
        ))
        ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
        ->setTaxClassId(1)
        ->setCreatedAt(time())
        ->setName($row['name'])
        ->setSku($sku)
        ->setPrice($row['price'])
        ->setCategoryIds(array(2))
        ->setStatus(1) // enabled
        ->setWeight(1)
        ->setWebsiteIDs(array(1))
        ->setDescription($row['description'])
        ->setShortDescription($row['short_desc']);

    try
    {
        $Parentproduct->save();

        $parent_id = $Parentproduct->getId();
        echo 'Configurable Product created: ' . $parent_id . "\n";

        if (!empty($parent_id))
        {
            foreach ($row['children'] as $child_sku => $child)
            {
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                $product->setAttributeSetId(4)
                    ->setTypeId('simple')
                    ->setStockData(array(
                        'manage_stock'  => 0,
                        'min_sale_qty'  => 0,
                        'max_sale_qty'  => 0,
                    ))
                    ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
                    ->setTaxClassId(1)
                    ->setCreatedAt(time())
                    ->setName($row['name'] . ' ' . $color)
                    ->setSku($sku . $child_sku)
                    ->setPrice($row['price'])
                    ->setcategoryIds(array(2))
                    ->setStatus(1)
                    ->setWeight(1)
                    ->setWebsiteIDs(array(1))
                    ->setDescription($row['description'])
                    ->setShortDescription($row['short_desc']);

                $product->save();

                echo 'Simple product created: ' . $product->getId() . "\n";
            }

            echo "\n";

        $Parentproduct

        Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')
    ->saveProducts($Parentproduct, $simpleProductIds);
    //or 
    Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
    ->saveProducts($Parentproduct, $simpleProductIds);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo 'Unable to create product', "\n";
        echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    }
}
```